# Use semaphore to implement monitor

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore, monitor

I want to use Semaphore to implement Monitor. I create 2 class. Buffer and ThreadDemo. In class Buffer, I create method put() and get()  ( I get code from this page)

```
public void put(int input) throws InterruptedException {
    monitorSemaphore.acquire();
    boolean acquired = false;
    while (numberInBuffer == size) {
        // Equivalent of wait()
        if (acquired) {
            dec();
            notifyCalled.release();
        }
        inc();
        monitorSemaphore.release();
        notifyCalled.acquire();
        monitorSemaphore.acquire();
        acquired = true;
    }

    // Critical section
    buffer[last] = input;
    last = (last + 1) % size;
    numberInBuffer++;

    // Equivalent of notifyAll()
    for (int i = val(); i > 0; i--) {
        dec();
        notifyCalled.release();
    }

    monitorSemaphore.release();
}

public int get() throws InterruptedException {
    monitorSemaphore.acquire();

    boolean acquired = false;
    while (numberInBuffer == 0) {
        // Equivalent of wait()
        if (acquired) {
            dec();
            notifyCalled.release();
        }
        inc();
        monitorSemaphore.release();
        notifyCalled.acquire();
        monitorSemaphore.acquire();
        acquired = true;
    }

    // Critical section
    int temp = buffer[start];
    start = (start + 1) % size;
    numberInBuffer--;

    // Equivalent of notifyA(ll)
    for (int i = val(); i > 0; i--) {
        dec();
        notifyCalled.release();
    }

    monitorSemaphore.release(); 

    return temp;
}
```

In class TestThread, I create Thread-T1, Thread-T2. But I can't call put and Get in class Buffer.

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {
private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

   public TestThread(String name) {
       threadName = name;
       System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
            put(2);//I can't call this method
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            get(); //
            Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
     }
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }


   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }


public static void main(String[] args) {

      TestThread T1 = new TestThread( "Thread-1");
      T1.start();

      TestThread T2 = new TestThread( "Thread-2");
      T2.start();

}}
```

And if my code in class TestThread incorrect, please show me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think... Let's assume if you define the get() and put() method in Buffer class. Then you should initialize the class instance first before you call the in-class methods. Like the code below:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   private Buffer buffer;

   public TestThread(String name, Buffer buffer) {
       threadName = name;
       this.buffer = buffer;
       System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
            buffer.put(2);//I can't call this method
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            buffer.get(); //
            Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
     }
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }
}
```

Comment: How can I create object TestThread? TestThread T1 = new TestThread( "Thread-1", ???);

Comment: The "???" should be your Buffer object. That means you need to create an buffer object before you initialize the thread. Thereafter different threads can take the same buffer object as constructor input and then operate on the same Buffer object concurrently.

Comment: No problem. Good luck for your learning journey! Besides, you can accept my answer if you feel it's helpful :)